# SSIS : Unwanted line return on a dynamic connection string

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, connection-string, etl

In a SSIS package, I want to send data from several instance to a flat files. To do so I create a dynamic connection string made of 3 variables:

- ".txt"
- a Network path
- The file name (which is the instance Name variable (string) that i use elsewhere in my package)

When i evaluate my expression at this point i receive :

*For*

```
TRIM(@[User::FileName]+REPLACE(@[User::ServerName],"\\","")+@[User::ExtensionFile])
```

I receive

> \\test-01\TEMP\SQL01MyInstance.txt

But, when i run the job, it's unable to create the SQL01MyInstance.txt, and i receive as error :

> [Flat File Destination [11]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "\\test-01\TEMP\SQL01MyInstance
>   .txt".
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.

There's a unwanted space at the end filename, when i copy paste the error message elsewhere it appear to be a line return (before the .txt)

Does anybody know how can i get rid of it that line return (which i'm assuming is making the job fail) ?

**Edit 1:**

Rights on the destination folder are ok,  because there's another flat file that I create in case of errors and it's created normally after that failure; but not with a dynamic name (normal behavior)

Comment: are you running this package from a sql server agent job?

Comment: No, I'm running it directly from my visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove line return you can use `REPLACE()` function with `\r\n`

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(@[User::FileName]+REPLACE(@[User::ServerName],"\\","")+@[User::ExtensionFile]),"\r",""),"\n","")
```

Where

```
 \r  : carriadge return
 \n  : line feed
```

Comment: Working like perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The TRIM function only trims the space character (versus other functions which trim all white space):

> TRIM does not remove white-space characters such as the tab or line feed characters. Unicode provides code points for many different types of spaces, but this function recognizes only the Unicode code point 0x0020. When double-byte character set (DBCS) strings are converted to Unicode they may include space characters other than 0x0020 and the function cannot remove such spaces. To remove all kinds of spaces, you can use the Microsoft Visual Basic .NET Trim method in a script run from the Script component.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/trim-ssis-expression

You can try this first to see if it works (Trim first then concatenate):

```
TRIM(@[User::FileName]) + TRIM(REPLACE(@[User::ServerName],"\","")) + TRIM(@[User::ExtensionFile]))
```

If not then you'll have to do the recommended String.Trim() function using a Script Task/Component that the MSDN article recommends (again, Trim each variable first, then concatenate)

Comment: It's not working with that either, i'll try the Script/task Component option and keep you update. 
Note: But even without TRIM function i still have the same result when i "evaluate" the expression. The difference really come at the output